# Where will be the html manifest saved in the local machine?

Tags: html

I have a demo/home.html page with the manifest set to "demo.appcache"

```
<html lang="en" manifest="demo.appcache">
```

I expected a folder demo/demo.appcache folder to be created.

Comment: Just [read this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_manifest_in_HTML5).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The manifest and any downloaded files associated with it will be stored in the browser application cache. The browser manages the store. You won't see them in the local file system, nor are they accessible from the local file system.